# Scalable Express + Mongoose Sort and Limit Pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pagination

I'm trying to work out how I can paginate my data efficiently. If I have a url such as: `example.com/items?page=5`, how can I retrieve the correct records every single time (so that the same record doesn't show up on another page)? I thought to I'd have to first sort the DB records first, then use mongoose to do a range query such as the one below.

How does this fare when the amount of records scales rapidly? I'm worried that the sorting process will take far too long and bottleneck the process. Any advice?

```
Submission.find({
  /* First Case: Hour */
  created: { $lt: new Date(), $gt: new Date(year+','+month+','+day+','+hour+','+min+','+sec) } // Get results from start of current hour to current time.
  /* Second Case: Day */
  created: { $lt: new Date(), $gt: new Date(year+','+month+','+day) } // Get results from start of current day to current time.
  /* Third Case: Month */
  created: { $lt: new Date(), $gt: new Date(year+','+month) } // Get results from start of current month to current time.
  /* Fourth Case: Year */
  created: { $lt: new Date(), $gt: new Date(year) } // Get results from start of current year to current time.
})
```

Comment: Yeah sorting is necessary and it takes time but remember to index the field on which you want to sort.

Comment: awesome! thanks for that tip. I'll index my sort criteria :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work on following query:

```
var query = Model.find(conditions).sort(sort).skip(skip).limit(limit);
```

where

1. condition will be say { age: { $gt: 20 } }
2. sort will be say { name: 1}
3. skip will  be say 20
4. limit will be say 10

then execute the following query to get the records

```
return query
        .exec()
        .then(function (cursor) { ...... });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm just worried that according to `https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/`, the `skip()` method is "CPU intensive. With larger collections, cursor.skip() may become IO bound"

Comment: How to get total number of pages?